# Is there a way that VSCode recognize javascript code between custom tags?

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code

I have a php file with some javascript code at the end but I have to put it between custom tags (they act like `<script></script>`). The problem is the code is not recognized as javascript between these tags (no coloration and no auto indent).

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdcM1.png)

Is there a way to solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, hope somebody else does, but why would you even insert javascript like this into a website?

Comment: modify the PHP TextMate file and define a JavaScript region (inject language), save this file because it will be overwritten on update

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you for your response but where can I find this PHP TextMate file ?

Comment: in the extension that does your PHP syntax highlighting